Split polygon at narrowest points
I have a massive polygon that looks like this :

This is only a snippet of it. Given its size, it would be best to split it at its narrowest points. I've tried finding a potential solution for this and so far the closest has been this answer from this very forum : Splitting polygons at narrowest part using R?
Has anyone here done something similar or has any ideas?
Update :
Some further details, the large polygons represents a region and the holes represent buffers from residential areas. I wish there would be a ways to break the polygon into smaller pieces to faciltate the analysis. These polygons will represent areas prone to wind turbine implantation and so they are going to have parcels attached to them, that's why I want them to be tinier.

Why do you want to split it? It is still going to be connected somewhere else so I dont understand

You might want to keep de-buffering the complex polygon till your resultant polygons are not simple. A simple polygon is a polygon without a hole. Start with a small buffer and increase it in slow steps at every steps check whether polygon is simple or not.

Your ultimate goal is to split the massive polygon into smaller parts?

Would it not be an alternative to apply a grid over the polygons and split the polygons based on the grid cells? Like intersection of grid with polygons? See also here for negative buffering, as proposed by @Abhilshit https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/402789/88814

Thank you so much, I'm going to try both of these solutions and I will get back to you!

Another option, if you just want to split it is Subdivide
